# Wordpress behind AWS ELB: constant 302, or not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress, amazon-elb

I have just installed a new WP under EC2, behind ELB.

ELB itself is secured, however, EC2's httpd is not.

Crazy Wordpress doesn't recognize it's being served on HTTPS, and installs itself in HTTP mode, then when I change the URLs in the General/settings, it gives me a nice endless redirect loop.

Tried everything I found:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'
```

into `wp-config.php`, redirect commands into `.htaccess`.

But WP's install script is failing from point0:

https://staging.example.com/wp-admin/install.php:

[image]

ALL these files are asked from HTTP, in spite I have the above command in wp-config set before loading up the installer.

So how the hack can I hack WP onto Amazon?